# Duplicate YARN conf settins

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm am using hadoop 2.6

In yarn-site.xml I have the following defined:

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

But if I look inside the yarn UI /conf URL I get the following 2 definitions:

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanamger.vmem-check-enabled</name>
   <value>false</value>
   <source>java.io.BufferedInputStream@2893de87</source>
</property>

<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
   <value>true</value>
   <source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

Which one of the two properties are actually being followed? 
Am I correct in saying that the `<source>java.io.BufferedInputStream@2893de87</source>` overwrites  `<source>yarn-default.xml</source>` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<source>` is not the property `value`.

The value is read from your configuration through some external source (an InputStream), then it is placed in the file with `<value>false</value>`

How that file gets read is up to the `Configuration` object in the Hadoop API.

Comment: What confuses me is which one of the two properties are being used by yarn; considering that the yarn conf UI is tells me that `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` are both `true` and `false`.

Comment: A configuration object is just a Hashmap underneath. And the defaults are overwritten with user-provided values in all cases